# boxplot on groupby timegrouper without subplots using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I am doing a groupby using pd.timegrouper on a time series dataset. When I am plotting a boxplot on this groupby object,it has subplots. I dont want to divide the plot area into subplots. I tried using the parameter `subplots=False`,but its throwing an error saying KEY ERROR "value".
This is the plot i am getting with subplots.
[image]

the code:

```
df['timestamp1'] = df['timestamp'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')
df=df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key="timestamp1",freq="3H"),group_keys=True,as_index=True)
df.boxplot(column="value",subplots=True)
```

The dataframe object i am using is:
[image]

I want to plot all the box plots in the same area without dividing it into subplots
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are getting subplots because you are plotting with the groupby object and not a dataframe. Every group is being plotted. `df` is no longer a dataframe. You need to perform some aggregation/transformation/apply on your groupby object and then plot.

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a bug. You can get the desired outcome by selecting only the timestamp1 and value columns, therefore eliminating the need to use the column parameter.

```
df[['timestamp1', 'value']].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3H', key='timestamp1'))\
                           .boxplot(subplots=False)
```

I went ahead and [submitted an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) for this on github.